# Replace a value in a script within Rails, from another script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have this in my the middle of my `show.html.erb`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#map<%= shop.id %>").gMap({ markers: [{ latitude: <%= shop.lat %>,
   longitude: <%= shop.lng %>,
   html: "<%=h shop.name %><br/><a href='http://maps.google.com/maps?q=<%=h shop.address_geo %>' target='_blank'>See Full Map</a>" },
  ],
  zoom: 16 });
</script>
```

Then at the bottom of it, I wanna do something like this:

```
function append_place(type) {
      var shop_id = id;
      $("shop_id").append(shop_id);
    }
```

Where I want the `id` to be replaced with `<%= shop.id %>`. I know both scripts are wrong in coding, but how do I implement it? Can't use Rails cos this is client-side and JSON. It first extracts the `id` from database, then append it via inline script.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could dump that variable into any number of places, but in the interest of keeping the global namespace clean, you could create a myPageVars object in the jquery object, for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $.myPageVars = $.myPageVars || {}; // don't want to overwrite any previously written vars
  $.myPageVars.shop_id = "<%= shop.id %>"

  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#map<%= shop.id %>").gMap({ markers: [{ latitude: <%= shop.lat %>,
   longitude: <%= shop.lng %>,
   html: "<%=h shop.name %><br/><a href='http://maps.google.com/maps?q=<%=h shop.address_geo %>' target='_blank'>See Full Map</a>" },
  ],
  zoom: 16 });
</script>
```

And your append function would look like this:

```
function append_place(type) {
  var shop_id = $.myPageVars.shop_id || false;
  if (shop_id) $("#map"+shop_id).append(whatever);
}
```

Sorry if I am misunderstanding your question, I am not a rails user.

Comment: `var shop_id = $.myPageVars.shop_id || false;` seems to break all codes.